# Debugging Azure WebJob locally - recompile fails

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-webjobs

I have a webjob that I'm debugging locally as a console app. But once I stop the code from within VS2017 I'm unable to recompile the exe as I get the following error

`Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\******.******.exe" to "bin\Debug\******.******.exe". Access to the path 'bin\Debug\******.******.exe' is denied.`

When I look at the processes that are running theres nothing there that jumps out.

[image: Processes running]

I've closed VS and restarted it, but thats not cleared the issue.

Other than restarting my machine is there anything else I can try?

Comment: When this problem occurs, can you manually browse to the executable and delete it through Windows Explorer or the command line? Also, have you checked your entire process list in Task Manager for the executable? And if you've still had no luck, can we see the contents of your Program.cs file for this WebJob?

Comment: @RobReagan - I tried that, but couldn't find anything obvious that was the job, there were no Console windows. I've ended up rebooting my machine

Comment: You need to use the Details tab in Task Manager to see the full process list. Check if your WebJobs is running. You can also use SysInternals 'handle' tool to see who has the handle.

Comment: It seems that some files are used by other process, If restart the OS is acceptable, please have a try to restart the OS and try to use administrator user to run the VS, it will be solved.

Comment: Is there any updates about this thread?

Comment: @TomSun not at the moment, been uploading to server and using the TextWriter to work out whats going on

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows `Resource Monitor` tool. Once opened, navigate to the `CPU` tab and enter the full path of the `.exe` (e.g. C:\Project\bin\debug\App.exe) in the `Search Handles` text box in the bottom-mid right corner and search. You should see the list of processes currently locking on the particular resource (in this case, the .exe). Select all the unwanted processes, right-click and end process. Depending upon on the version of Windows you are running, the experience might differ a bit but the general idea is more or less the same.